# Mössbauer effect to verify the gravitational redshift

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-redshift

> "The tower used by Pound and Rebka in 1960 to exploit the Mossbauer effect is only about h = 20 meters high, and so the effect (gravitational redshift) is only $(GM/(Rc^2))(h/R) ∼ 10−15$! How would one of do the experiment?”

This question was asked in the middle of the theory in the book A.Zee, I don't want to see the answer immediately, so that i would appreciate any tip to think in a effective experiment to measure the  gravitational redshift predicted by the equivalence principle.

Particularly, i thought that we could bring one of this crystals to the top tower, and make the crystal in the earth floor emits a signal, such that the signal arrives at the other crystal. Now here i guess that if the frequency does not change, the other crystal would be excited and emit as the first crystal emit. To support my statement, i used the fact that [Mössbauer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect) is about sharp emission wrt frequency. But i am not sure "how sharp" is the resonance width in this Mössbauer effect, actually i know very little about the phenomenon.

Comment: $10-15$ Do you mean $10^{-15}$?

Answer (score 1):

In an experiment like the one you're wondering about, typically the crystal would be moved back and forth in a sinusoidal fashion.  When the crystal moves at a speed that Doppler shifts the incoming radiation to the resonant frequency, the crystal will absorb the incoming radiation.  Timing of the detected signal relative to the motion of the crystal, and of course the range of velocities of the crystal's motion, reveal the gravitational frequency shift.  You are right that the resonance bandwidth is an important factor, but if gamma radiation is being used, the bandwidth is small enough that it won't matter.